# How to retrieve element value in xml using java

Tags: java, xml

Here is the xml from which i want to retrieve the value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dsml SYSTEM "http://www.example.com">
<dsml>
<entries>
<entry dn="uid=7686,c=in,ou=pages,o=example.com">
<att name="uid">
<value>7568766</value>
</att><att name="callname">
<value>jhsadkjh</value>
</att></entry>
<entry dn="uid=8979879,c=in,ou=pages,o=example.com">
<att name="uid">
<value>7983274</value>
</att><att name="callname">
<value>hdsakjh</value>
</att></entry>
<entry dn="uid=8687686,c=in,ou=pages,o=example.com">
<att name="callname">
<value>aksdjklsaj</value>
</att><att name="uid">
<value>lkljdslkajd</value>
</att></entry>
</entries></dsml>
```

I want retrieve the value of attribute name = "callname".

Right now i am using:
NodeList subs = doc.getElementsByTagName("callname");

But it is returning null for me.

Thanks
Shashank

Comment: Consider to use XPath (http://www.studytrails.com/java/xml/jaxp/java-api-for-xml-xpath.jsp) and an XPath expression like `//att[@name = 'callname']/value`.

Comment: @MartinHonnenThanks man!! It worked for me.

Comment: Martin is crazy skilled. Though, he posts many answers in comments.. that he should post as an answer :)

Comment: How to retrieve element tag value of XHTML using Java?